# Trait enforcing impl of method for subtypes

Tags: scala

Is it possible in Scala to enforce the implementation of a typed trait for subclasses with the type of the subclass? Ie. I'd like to define a trait which forces all subtypes to implement Ordered for *only the concrete subtype*. So I want to ensure that every implementation *TraitImpl* of the trait *ATrait* implements *Ordered[TraitImpl]*. Below is a non working example to illustrate what I am trying to do.

```
trait ATrait extends Ordered[_ <: ATrait] {
}

class TraitImpl extends ATrait {
    override def compare(that: TraitImpl): Int = ???
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Sheng is right, F-bounded polymorphism is probably the way to go, but the code offered is incomplete in that it will allow the following.

```
trait ATrait[T <: ATrait[T]] extends Ordered[T]

class B extends ATrait[B] {
  override def compare(that: B): Int = ???
}
class C extends ATrait[B] {
  override def compare(that: B): Int = ???
}
```

This bleeding of `B` into `C` is not what you want. A more complete implementation would be as such.

```
trait ATrait[T <: ATrait[T]] {
  self: T with Ordered[T] =>
}

class B extends ATrait[B] with Ordered[B] {
  override def compare(that: B): Int = ???
}
class C extends ATrait[C] with Ordered[C] {
  override def compare(that: C): Int = ???
}
```

With this you can't use `Ordered[B]` in the definition of `C`.

**update**

Or, a slightly more concise rendition as @Sheng has kindly pointed out.

```
trait ATrait[T <: ATrait[T]] extends Ordered[T] {self: T =>}

class B extends ATrait[B] {
  def compare(that: B): Int = ???
}
class C extends ATrait[C] {
  def compare(that: C): Int = ???
}
```

Comment: Indeed, your code is more sound :) I wonder why you write `self: T with Ordered[T]` instead of `trait ATrait[T <: ATrait[T]] { self: T` such that you have to write `with Ordered[T]` for each subclass?

Comment: @Sheng, Good point. I was just working from my notes on how F-bounding works. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a F-bounded type:

```
trait ATrait[T <: ATrait[T]] extends Ordered[T] {
}

class TraitImpl extends ATrait[TraitImpl] {
    override def compare(that: TraitImpl): Int = ???
}
```

Update: as pointed out by @jwvh, this is not unbreakable as `class TraitImpl extends ATrait[B]` also compiles, given B is another subclass of ATrait. Please refer to his anwser for a more complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the most elegant solution would be usage of self-annotation :

```
trait ATtrait[T] { self: Ordered[T] =>
}
```

Every class implementing this trait has to also implement ordered, and you can use ordered methods inside ATrait.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you "step outside the box" you could fair better with a context bound. Fortunately, Scala offers you two flavours of implementing order, the second of which being through implicits.

```
trait A extends Ordered[T <: A[T]] {
  def compare(that: T)(implicit ordering: Ordering[T]): Int = {
    ordering.compare(this, that)
  }
}

class TraitImpl extends A[TraitImpl]
```

Now you can insert the `Ordering` at call site and save yourself the trouble of constantly overriding things in any form, wherever you end up calling `compare` that's where that implicit will be required.

You can control your default ordering imports with some kind of `package object`, so you would offer a much better importing experience to your users or colleagues.

Comment: But I would need to implement Ordering anyway, so I dont think that using an implicit Ordering saves me much work in my use case.

Comment: @PhilBa It makes it a lot cleaner and separates concern properly, your model currently doesn't do that and quite frankly smells.

Comment: I'm not sure how implementing logic specific to an object in that object is a code smell, but I thank you for the time you took to answer. Also please understand that this was just a specific example to a general question.